# Node v8 variable default NULL but reassign based on argument passed

Tags: c, v8

I'm sure it's really basic but I haven't been able to find anything like it (perhaps I'm going about it completely the wrong way).. I'm trying to pass str to the 'call_to_c_lib_func' function which takes either NULL or a string (char*).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <v8.h>

void test(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  char *str = NULL;
  if (!args[3]->IsNull() && !args[3]->IsUndefined()) {
    String::Utf8Value arg_str(args[3]->ToString());
    str = *arg_str;
  }
  // Following function takes either NULL or char*
  call_to_c_lib_func(str);
}
```

Edit: Post originally contained simplified C code for this which didn't really help explain the problem, hopefully this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask an actual question!

Comment: also, using `strlen` and `strncpy` isn't safer than `strcpy`; the length of the string is inferred from the data it self, which might or might not be a zero-terminated C string, not leading or leading to copying of data that shouldn't be copied.

Comment: You still haven't asked a question or explained what problem you are having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post doesn't ask a question or explain what problem you are having with the code. So I am assuming you ran the code exactly as posted and sometimes the call to the function behaves oddly or crashes.

---

Your existing code fails because:

```
String::Utf8Value arg_str(args[3]->ToString());
```

is inside a `{` code block `}` but you try to access its contents after that code block has exited (and therefore after `arg_str` has been destroyed).

Instead you could write:

```
String::Utf8Value temp;
char *str = NULL;

if (!args[3]->IsNull() && !args[3]->IsUndefined())
{
    temp = args[3]->ToString();
    str = *temp;
}

call_to_c_lib_func( str );
```

Of course there are many ways to skin a cat, just watch out when using `v8::String` that you do not use the result of `operator*` after the string has been destroyed, because it returns a pointer to the content of the string.

NB. I'm not familiar with V8 so there may be a more elegant way of accessing `args[3]`'s string data that neither of us is aware of.

Comment: Thanks, this does explain it. However I was wondering how it could be structured if there were multiple arguments (without using lots of nested if statments of course)? Would it then be sensible to copy the string value so it's accessible outside of the if block?

Comment: @gratz Have updated the code to avoid duplication of the library call. The key point is that the `String::Utf8Value` object has to still exist while you have a pointer to its contents active.

Comment: Don't seem to be able to declare 'String::Utf8Value temp;' on a separate line to assigning to it so I've done this instead: 'String::Utf8Value temp(args[3]->ToString());' followed by the if block which contains 'str = *temp;'. Doesn't seem quite right because I'm converting to string before checking it isn't null or undefined but it seems to work ok.. Thanks